# Web-scrape for link with Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I again have a problem extracting a specific link with Scrapy. Here the HTML excerpt:

```
<section class="test">
                    <div class="Testclass">
                        <form id="Form" name="FormName" method="get" action="#plpPaginationAnchor">
    <select id="pageSelectionBottom" name="page">
        <option value="0" disabled="" selected="">
                        Seite&nbsp;1&nbsp;von&nbsp;2</option>
                <option value="1">2</option>
                </select>
    <input type="hidden" name="sort" value="code-asc">
    <input type="hidden" name="q" value=":code-asc">
        <a class="nextpage" href="**LINK**" data-action="next" data-flight="control">
            <i class="icon="Next"></i>
        </a>
    </form>
```

I need the Link in the href Tag. Among other things, I tried the following:

```
url = response.css('div.testclass > a::attr(href)').extract_first()
```

I would be very grateful if someone could help me here.

Comment: Whats the site being scraped by the way, so I can test this properly.

Comment: A few more thngs may be my method using scrapy may be different then what your looking for reason being no python code was really provided besides `url = response.css('div.testclass > a::attr(href)').extract_first()` But either way it should help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, when I try it with: response.css("section > div > form > a::attr(href)").extract_first() I get the Link. I don't know if this is the best solution now, but it works,

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to do in scrapy shell:

```
> from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse
> 
> response = HtmlResponse(url="Test HTML String", body='<section class="test"><div class="Testclass"><form id="Form" name="FormName" method="get" action="#plpPaginationAnchor"><select id="pageSelectionBottom" name="page"><option value="0" disabled="" selected="">Seite&nbsp;1&nbsp;von&nbsp;2</option><option value="1">2</option></select><input type="hidden" name="sort" value="code-asc"><input type="hidden" name="q" value=":code-asc"><a class="nextpage" href="**LINK**" data-action="next" data-flight="control"><i class="icon="Next"></i></a></form>', encoding='utf-8')
> 
> response.css('a::attr(href)').extract_first()
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `BeautifulSoup` along with `requests`?

Heres a example using this module:

```
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

    l = requests.get(search)
    page = l.text
    soup= bs(page,'html.parser')
    link = soup.findAll('a',attrs={'class':'nextpage'})
```

something like this I from what Ive used works, I may have to edit this post later on but using `bs4` and `requests` is still a valid method.

You may not want to do `findAll` if there is more then one `<a>`, if they have the same class (for example youtube has this for each video, and using findall will get each video url for the search) it will retrieve the link

Comment: Thanks. Yes bs4 would be a option. I would just like to do it with Scrapy, because the whole crawler already works with Scrapy.

Comment: Alright, well ill get you a response to your question with the use of Scrapy. it will take me a minute or two but Ill get it to you.

Answer (score 0):

`url = response.css('div.testclass > form > a::attr(href)').extract_first()`

Your original selector is looking for `a`s that exist as direct descendants of `div.testclass`. You want to look inside `form`s that are direct descendants of `div.testclass`, based on the structure of your snippet.

You could also try this:

`url = response.css('div.testclass a::attr(href)').extract_first()`

but it won't be as specific.